# Setting config vars in Heroku doesn't work for GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS

Tags: node.js, heroku, dialogflow-es

I'm pursuing a tutorial about building a chatbot using google dialogflow and nodejs. Now I'm on deploying it to Heroku. I don't want to add credentials directly. Instead I want to add them using config vars. So I made a separate file for saving credentials like this.

```
module.exports = {
    googleProjectID: process.env.GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID,
    dialogFlowSessionID: process.env.DIALOGFLOW_SESSION_ID,
    dialogFlowSessionLanguageCode: process.env.DIALOGFLOW_LANGUAGE_CODE,
    googleClientEmail : process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_EMAIL,
    googlePrivateKey : process.env.GOOGLE_PRIVATE_KEY
};
```

Next I set config vars through the settings of heroku. Like this...

[image]

And I promise you that I have added values to those keys 100% correctly. But my application gives me errors. If looking at "heroku logs --tail" facilitates you in giving answers [please use this link](https://github.com/mastrmind-dev/chatbot/blob/main/heroku_logs.txt) to look at heroku log.

But when I using below code instead of above code

```
module.exports = {
    googleProjectID : "<real value>",
    dialogFlowSessionID : "<real value>",
    dialogFlowSessionLanguageCode : "<real value>",
    googleClientEmail : "<real value>",
    googlePrivateKey : "<real value>"
}
```

I added values directly, instead of using 'config var'. Then It works without any problems. But I want to do it using config vars. Please Help Me.......

Comment: I Know I Haven't Added Additional codes. But I realized problem is only with that code. So I want to know what's wrong with that...

Comment: Quick question, is the Google key still valid and in your code are you using ```process.env.<Name>``` properly without any typo? I am asking cause you seem to have configured your keys properly

Comment: @NtshemboHlongwane=>I'm sorry for asking. But please tell me what do you mean by "Google key"? To second question, I'm not using process.env.<name> anywhere in my code except process.env.port. I use those object names instead of using process.env.<name>

Comment: Ain't you have having problems with Google key here not working? So I am asking isn't it expired? Secondly when you have you ```env vars``` in your heroku configs then why don't you eliminate the way you handling things and access them directly using ```process.env.<Name of var>```

Comment: Ok. When I use those credential values directly, it doesn't give me any errors. So I think nothing is expired. Secondly I tried to access `env vars` directly as you said. But unfortunately it didn't fix anything or didn't change anything.

Comment: Do you have ```dotenv``` package so that it can work in dev mode? And when you have deployed on heroku ```process.env.<Name>``` should work unless you have some typos either in code or the key entered in heroku configs is misspelled